# "go test -cpuprofile" does not generate a full trace

Tags: go, pprof

**Issue**

I have a go package, with a test suite.

When I run the test suite for this package, the total runtime is ~ 7 seconds :

```
$ go test ./mydbpackage/ -count 1
ok      mymodule/mydbpackage    7.253s
```

However, when I add a `-cpuprofile=cpu.out` option, the sampling does not cover the whole run :

```
$ go test ./mydbpackage/ -count 1 -cpuprofile=cpu.out
ok      mymodule/mydbpackage    7.029s

$ go tool pprof -text -cum cpu.out
File: mydbpackage.test
Type: cpu
Time: Aug 6, 2020 at 9:42am (CEST)
Duration: 5.22s, Total samples = 780ms (14.95%)     # <--- depending on the runs, I get 400ms to 1s
Showing nodes accounting for 780ms, 100% of 780ms total
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
         0     0%     0%      440ms 56.41%  testing.tRunner
      10ms  1.28%  1.28%      220ms 28.21%  database/sql.withLock
      10ms  1.28%  2.56%      180ms 23.08%  runtime.findrunnable
         0     0%  2.56%      180ms 23.08%  runtime.mcall
      ...
```

Looking at the collected samples :

```
# sample from another run :
$ go tool pprof -traces cpu.out | grep "ms "  # get the first line of each sample
      10ms   runtime.nanotime
      10ms   fmt.(*readRune).ReadRune
      30ms   syscall.Syscall
      10ms   runtime.scanobject
      10ms   runtime.gentraceback
      ...
# 98 samples collected, for a total sum of 1.12s
```

The issue I see is : for some reason, the sampling profiler stops collecting samples, or is blocked/slowed down at some point.

**Context**

go version is 1.14.6, platform is linux/amd64

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.6 linux/amd64
```

This package contains code that interact with a database, and the tests are run against a live postgresql server.

One thing I tried : `t.Skip()` internally calls `runtime.Goexit()`, so I replaced calls to `t.Skip` and variants with a simple `return` ; but it didn't change the outcome.

**Question**

Why aren't more samples collected ? I there some known pattern that blocks/slows down the sampler, or terminates the sampler earlier than it should ?

Comment: cpuprofile _samples_ what the CPU does, it is _never_ a "full capture". What works well is running  a Benchmark function like `go test -run X -bench BenchmarkReadDB -cpuprofile cpu.out` as benchmarks are repeated often and thus sampling the CPU yields the desired information.  So no, this is not a known issue, this is how CPU sampling _works_.

Comment: I fully agree with yoru "full capture" decription, however, in practive, I would expect the sampling to cover a very big chunk of the 7s run. In the above case, I only get ~ 70 samples (I checked with `go tool pprof -traces`, and each single sample is reported to cover 10ms, with a few reported at 20ms). My real question is, as stated above : why aren't more samples collected ? I there some known pattern that blocks the sampler ?

Comment: Updated my question, to mention the samples and rephrase the final question

Comment: If your code doesn't do much not much samples will be collected. Code waiting for IO does nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't I at least have samples saying "waiting on IO" ? (like `syscall.Syscall` above)

Comment: @Volker : I re-read the docs for pprof, and understood that the cpuprofile only measured active goroutines. Thanks for pointing in that direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Volker guided me to the answer in his comments :
`-cpuprofile` creates a profile in which only goroutines actively using the CPU are sampled.

In my use case : my go code spends a lot of time waiting for the answers of the postgresql server.

Generating a trace using `go test -trace=trace.out`, and then extracting a network blocking profile using `go tool trace -pprof=net trace.out > network.out` yielded much more relevant information.

For reference, on top of opening the complete trace using `go tool trace trace.out`, here are the values you can pass to `-pprof=` :

> *from [`go tool trace` docs](https://golang.org/cmd/trace/) :*
>
> - net: network blocking profile
> - sync: synchronization blocking profile
> - syscall: syscall blocking profile
> - sched: scheduler latency profile